# Add checkboxes and actions for a list of database items

Tags: php, symfony, controller, twig, symfony-forms

This is my controller, I'm using KNPpaginator to get current user's messages and pass them to a twig view.

```
 $messages = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('PrivateMessageBundle:Message');
    // $messageList = $messages->findBy(array('receiver' => $this->getUser()));

    $mymsg = $messages->findMyMessages($this->getUser());

    $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $mymsg,
        $request->query->get('page', 1)/*page number*/,
        10/*limit per page*/,
        array('defaultSortFieldName' => 'a.sentAt', 'defaultSortDirection' => 'desc')
    );


    return $this->render(
        '@PrivateMessage/inbox.html.twig',
        array(
            'messageList' => $pagination
        )
    );
```

findMyMessages returns a query for the current user's messages. It is mandatory for the KNPpaginator to work properly. I don't know why it doesn't work for arrays, it works only on queries for me.

```
public function findMyMessages($user)
{


    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->select('a')
        ->where('a.receiver = :user')
        ->andWhere('a.isSpam = false')
       // ->andWhere('a.replyof is NULL')
        ->Join('a.sender', 'r')
        ->setParameters(
            array('user' => $user)
        );


    return $qb->getQuery();
}
```

This is my Message entity, it represents what a message between two users could have: title, content, sender, receiver, date etc.

```
class Message
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="private_message.title.blank")
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=50)
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="private_message.receiver.blank")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MedAppBundle\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $receiver;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MedAppBundle\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $sender;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="private_message.content.blank")
     * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="string")
     */
    protected $content;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="sentAt", type="datetime")
     */
    protected $sentAt;


    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="isSpam", type="boolean")
     */
    protected $isSpam = false;


    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="seenAt", type="datetime",nullable=true)
     */
    protected $seenAt = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PrivateMessageBundle\Entity\Message")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id",nullable=true)
     */
    protected $replyof;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PrivateMessageBundle\Entity\Message", mappedBy="replyof")
     **/
    private $replies;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->replies = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

And in my view, I have a more complex display, but for the sake of demonstration, I've simplified it a bit:

```
  {% for message in messageList %}

      {{ message.title|e }}
      {{ message.sender|e }}
      {{ message.content }}

      <div class="message-action">
          <a class="" href="{{ path('private_message_mark',{'msg': message.id}) }}">Spam </a> |
          <a class="" href="{{ path('private_message_new',{'msg': message.id}) }}">Reply </a>
          <input type="checkbox" id="message{{ message.id }}" class="checkbox"
                                   name="_message{{ message.id }}"/>
      </div>

  {% endfor %}
```

Now, what I'm trying to do is have a checkbox displayed for each message (exactly like Gmail has), and a dropdown with certain actions(delete, mark as spam, etc.) and depending on the action selected apply it to the checked messages.

This is a bit more complex, I'm not sure if I should modify my MessageType formbuilder and add more unmapped fields, or should I make a new one? I've added a checkbox for each message, but I don't think it's properly. How can I make a connection between them and a dropdown with actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're nearly there, you're setting the ID and name for the checkboxes, what I'd do is set the value for the checkbox to the ID and simply set the name to whatever you like (it wouldn't be handled by the symfony form).

e.g.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="{{ message.id }}" class="checkbox"
                               id="kbIdList_{{ message.id }}" name="kbIdList[]"/>
```

(Setting the input id to kbIdList_{{ message.id }} means that you can easily reference the checkbox via javascript for a given row ID if you need to)

You'd have to get these out of the Request object in the controller action that handles the form post. Note post values can often be in the $request->request object for some reason.

e.g.

```
$checkedList = $request->request->get("kbIdList");
```

All being well, $checkedList should contain an array of IDs for you to process. to know what to do, add a select input with a list of operations, or add a series of form buttons etc...

Comment: Hm, you're right. Post values do go in the Request object, forgot about that. I kind of wanted to make this a bit more reusable since I'd have checkboxes on more tables and having to add them like this and parse the request object instead of a Form object is a bit more troublesome.

Comment: I agree its not all nicely encapsulated with the form, but in my experience of Symfony forms, its usually quicker to do the above than try and get Symfony forms to work out you want it to!

I'm sure a forms expert will come along and offer a solution, but suffice to say it'll probably be more code spread across the FormType class and controller - at least the solution above is simple and I'd argue just as easy to wrap in a service layer method if you want to have the code centralised.